# Append the current date and time to the file name

Tags: files, date, cp

What can I add to this command to append the current date and time to the file name?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "*.*" -exec cp -p -t /new/location {} \+
```

Comment: filename only. Not content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "*.*" -exec cp -p {} /new/location/{}-$(date +%Y-%m-%d) \;`

I have removed the target (`-t`) parameter from the `cp` command and described the path and filename.

`{}` is used as a placeholder for the file name, to which we append a `date` in the desired format.

The example formatting `+%Y-%m-%d` should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

```
_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)
```

for the date *and time*, (or `date +%F_%T` for short in most `date` implementations).

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
now=${(%):-%D{%FT%T%z}} # using prompt expansion with the %
                        # parameter expansion flag

# or (using the strftime builtin)
zmodload zsh/datetime
strftime -s now %FT%T%z $EPOCHSECONDS

# or (using the date external utility)
now=$(date +%FT%T%z)

# optional:
zmodload zsh/files # to enable a cp builtin which would speed
                   # things up considerably if you have
                   # zillions of files to copy.

zmv -C '^*.*(#q.)' '/new/localtion/$f-$now'
```

`(#q.)` is a glob qualifier that selects *regular* files only (like `find`'s `-type f`).